# Port already in use

Tags: python, windows, arduino

I am on a Windows 7 computer, trying to use Python to run a simple program on my Arduino to make it blink.

For some reason, whenever I attempt to run the script in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), I receive an error that the port is already open. I have tried restarting my computer, changing Arduinos, changing the USB port that I have plugged into, running a different program that I am quite sure closes the computers connection to the port. However, I am still getting the same error.

I am quite new to Python and Arduino, so there might be something stupidly easy that I am forgetting. I have asked a friend who is more experienced and he spoke of it being a problem with Windows.

Here is the relevant code. The class I used in Python is as follows.

```
import serial
import socket
import glob
import pickle
from time import sleep,time

class Ardustat():
    def __init__(self):
        self.port = ""
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.mode = "serial"
        self.debug = False

    def findPorts(self):
        """A commands to find possible ardustat ports with no Arguments, """
        return glob.glob("COM*")

    def connect(self,port):
        if self.mode == "serial":
            self.ser = serial.Serial(port,57600)
            self.ser.timeout = 1 # what does this do?
            self.ser.open()
            return "connected to serial"
```

And the Python code is

```
from ardustat_library_simple_dan import Ardustat
import time

serial_port = 'COM6'
ard = Ardustat()

#Connect to the irritating ardustat
ard.connect(serial_port)

for a in range(0,5):
    ard.blink(serial_port)
    time.sleep(.2)
```

The Arduino code is long, but in the setup there is the following code.

```
void setup()
{
    //Startup Serial
    Serial.begin(57600);
    //  Serial.println("Hi Dan!");
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Have you ruled out that it's not a permissions issue on the port?  Is power shell the default shell for Windows 7, or can you use something simpler?

Comment: Pretty sure its not a permission issue, because it has let me open the port before. The issue is that it always thinks the port is already open. I have run other programs to try and close it with no luck.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I can see a few reasons why this is not working:

1. You have your serial monitor running while you're running your script:

   - The serial port can only be open once on a given host, if you try to open it twice, the second program to open it will report it as already opened.
2. You did not open the serial connection on the Arduino side:

   - You say you run a blink [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch). If that's the default `blink.ino`, it does not open the serial port and your system may report the serial port is not openable (and I don't know [Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), but I wouldn't be surprised to see an inconsistent error happening)
   - You wrote your own blink sketch, but you did not put `Serial.begin(115200);` in the `setup()` of your sketch file.
3. You open the port twice (or more) in the [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) code.

   - You shall have only one `serial.open()` statement in your code.

So first, check your code to be sure you do *actually* use the serial port from within the Arduino sketch. You can paste your code in your question so we can check that out.

Then, check your Python code to be sure you do *actually* open the serial port once and only once within your script.

Finally, be sure to not have another program opening the serial port while you're running your script, usually one tend to test the connection with Arduino's serial monitor, let it open and try to open the port using a script, which does not work. I saw that very often from beginners.

And I vote for... problem #3 \o/

```
class Ardustat():
    def __init__(self):
        self.port = ""
        self.ser = serial.Serial()  # Here you open the port once
        self.mode = "serial"
        self.debug = False

    def findPorts(self):
        """A commands to find possible ardustat ports with no Arguments, """
        return glob.glob("COM*")

    def connect(self,port):
        if self.mode == "serial":
            self.ser = serial.Serial(port,57600) # Here you open the port twice
```

I did not check [pySerial's](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) source code, but I'm pretty sure `serial.Serial()` opens up the first serial port it finds available at its default speed. Therefore, as you don't close the connection from the first instance of `self.ser`, the second instance gets crazy saying "dude, it's already opened!".

That's why you'd better not add an abstraction (`Artustat`) over a correct abstraction (`pyserial.Serial`), but just use correctly the tools and do something like:

```
with serial.Serial(port, speed) as ser:
    do_blink(ser)
```

where `do_blink()` is a function where you do your stuff. The `with` statement over `serial.Serial` will take care of the life of the serial port object (opening it when you enter the block, closing it as you exit the block).

Comment: cheers! i thought it might be that after thinking for a good few hours.